# my mysql query doesn't update my table

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query=UPDATE americana SET 7='99' WHERE Bdate='2011-04-15';

mysql_query($query);
```

7 is a column name and Bdate too
it doesn't update my table?

Answer (score 10):

if so enclose it with backtick "`"

```
$query="UPDATE americana SET `7`='99' WHERE Bdate='2011-04-15'";
```

Comment: its **backtick "`" key before 1 in keyboard** **not single quote**

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="UPDATE americana SET `7`='99' WHERE Bdate='2011-04-15'";
mysql_query($query);
```

The query should be enclosed in quotes and also marked column name with backtick(`)sign if it has name with starting from numeric value, try it now and see if it works better now...

Comment: the query is in quotes and i added the backtick it doesn't work

Comment: this is the error message that i'm getting: Database query faild: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''7'='99' WHERE 'Bdate'='2011-04-15'' at line 1

Comment: Actually u have not added a backtick but u have added a single quote which u can see in error massage here  :-  '7'='99'